# Label provider not called

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

The following code doesn't display text and long properly but the toString() of the Record class.

```
public class CodeCheckerPreferencePage extends PreferencePage
   implements
      IWorkbenchPreferencePage
{
   public CodeCheckerPreferencePage() {
      super( "Code checker statistics" );
   }

   @Override
   protected Control createContents( Composite parent ) {
      final TableViewer viewer =
         new TableViewer(
            parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL |
                    SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER );
      viewer.setContentProvider( ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
      viewer.setInput( Stats.getStats().getRecords());
      final Table table = viewer.getTable();
      table.setHeaderVisible( true );
      table.setLinesVisible( true );
      final TableViewerColumn colFile =
         new TableViewerColumn( viewer, SWT.NONE );
      colFile.getColumn().setWidth( 400 );
      colFile.getColumn().setText( "File" );
      colFile.setLabelProvider( new ColumnLabelProvider() {
         @Override public String getText( Object element ) {
            return ((Stats.Record)element).getFile(); }});
      final TableViewerColumn colConsumed =
         new TableViewerColumn( viewer, SWT.NONE );
      colConsumed.getColumn().setWidth( 80 );
      colConsumed.getColumn().setText( "Consumed ms" );
      colConsumed.setLabelProvider( new ColumnLabelProvider() {
         @Override public String getText( Object element ) {
            return String.format( "%3d",
                      ((Stats.Record)element).getConsumed()); }});
      final GridData gridData = new GridData();
      gridData.verticalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
      gridData.horizontalSpan = 2;
      gridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
      gridData.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
      gridData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
      viewer.getControl().setLayoutData(gridData);
      return table;
   }

   @Override
   public void init(IWorkbench workbench) {/**/}
}
```

The text displayed in the "File" column is "a.b.c.Stats$Record@750e313c" and no text is displayed in the "Consumed" column.

I have put breakpoints in the methods "getText": they are never reached.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Are you sure the contentprovider is not called? Can you post the code of `Stats.Record` `getFile()` Method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set up everything about the table **before** you call `setInput` so move the

```
  viewer.setInput( Stats.getStats().getRecords());
```

line to the end of the method.